# How to change x-axis labels in highcharts in month, week, quarter on condition?

Tags: highcharts

I want to change the x-axis label in highcharts in month, week and quarter depend on condition.
I have tried the following code :

```
xAxis: {
    scopeQ: this,
    type: 'datetime',
        tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 30 * 4,
    dateTimeLabelFormats: function() {          
    if(flag=='monthly') {
        return {month: '%b \'%y'}
    }
    else if(flag=='weekly') {
        return {week: '%e \' %b'}
        }
    else if(flag=='quarterly') {
        return {month: '%b \'%y'}
    }           
    },
    units: [
    [
        'month', [1]
    ],
    [
        'week', [1]
    ]
    ],
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
        if(flag=='monthly') {
           return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b \'%y', this.value)
        }
            else if(flag=='weekly') {
           return Highcharts.dateFormat('W%w \'%y', this.value)
        }
        else if(flag=='quarterly') {
           var quarter = Math.ceil((new Date(this.value).getMonth() + 1) / 3);
           return Highcharts.dateFormat('Q' + quarter + ' %Y' , this.value)
             }
    },
    rotation: 315,
    style: {
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
    },

},

},
```

I want to have the output for 
the month as - Jan'18 Feb'18
the week as - w1'18 w2'18
the quarter as - Q1'18 Q2'18

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By using the `units` property, you must keep the right order:

```
xAxis: {
    ...,
    units: [
        [
            'week', [1]
        ],
        [
            'month', [1]
        ]
    ]
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6do4xzur/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.units